# Is it possible to run APC on PHP 5.3.6/IIS/Windows 2008?

Tags: php, windows, iis, pac

The problem is that no binary I could find worked, the APC section never appears in the info display and the apc monitor states that APC is not running.

Is there a way to make APC + PHP + IIS work?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a fitting library.

Be aware of the version number though. From your phpinfo() or php -i you can find out which version you need:

There are three different factors:

- 32bit vs 64bit
- VC6 vs VC9 (Visual Studio Compiler version)

> If you are using PHP with Apache 1 or Apache2 from apache.org you need to use the VC6 versions of PHP
>
> If you are using PHP with IIS you should use the VC9 versions of PHP
>
> VC6 Versions are compiled with the legacy Visual Studio 6 compiler
>
> VC9 Versions are compiled with the Visual Studio 2008 compiler and have improvements in performance and stability. The VC9 versions require you to have the Microsoft 2008 C++ Runtime (x86) or the Microsoft 2008 C++ Runtime (x64) installed

See: http://windows.php.net/

- Thread safe vs Non thread safe. (TS/NTS)

```
php -i|grep VC
Compiler => MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Zend Extension Build => API220090626,TS,VC9
PHP Extension Build => API20090626,TS,VC9
```

I usually get them here (32bits):
http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

or here (64bits): http://www.anindya.com/

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes, but you will need, as you already know, a fitting binary. I think the problem is not so much IIS but rather windows in general - its also a pain to get an APC DLL working with Apache under windows.

So in short: if you spend much time compiling it yourself, you might succeed, but I do not know anybody who actually succeeded.